# Someone requested a topic and I created it. Now what?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-drafts

To get started with helping out with the documentation, I headed towards the google-chrome-extensions page and saw that a heavily requested topic was ["Developer Tools Integration"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension/topic-requests/3842), so i clicked the blue button beside it and wrote the topic.  I submitted it, a user commented to have me correct a few mistakes, I did, but nothing happened since then (a week ago).

I thought that once somebody wrote something for a requested topic, that topic could then be added to the documentation, and then other people could improve and add to the documentation from there.

I don't even understand where my article is now that I've written it.  It isn't listed in the "OVERVIEW TOPIC" grey menu, or anywhere else.  The only way I can access it is by going over the ["Requests"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension/topics?tab=requests) tab and clicking the "Create Topic" button next to "Developer Tools Integration".

It does say "Debugging Chrome Extensions will not be visible to others until your change is reviewed.", so does that mean that high-level members have a menu to accept my changes and make it public, or can nobody even find my changes?  Have I forgotten to press a publish button somewhere?  Please forgive me if I missed something obvious.

Here's the topic I created (the share link button gave me a url that didn't work):

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension/drafts/62885

Comment: Put examples next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't create it... yet. It's just a suggested edit waiting for review at this point:

> [image: That's OP!]

Anyone can see the change if they look at the [list of proposed changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension?tab=proposedchanges). (I checked in Incognito mode.)

At this point you can sit and wait for people to review things.